# In Neutopia why didn't the Borax Kid teleport in Scruffy?

Tags: futurama

Spoiler:

> At the end of the episode the Borax Kid appears to right everyone's genders, teleporting in those that aren't currently there (such as the crotchedy old woman) but leaves Scruffy in the toilet, thus leaving him a woman.

Why is Scruffy left out?

Comment: Because it's funny

Comment: For the hell of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scruffy was in the middle of using the toilet. Had he teleported him in, he would have been squatting over the ground and actively excreting. Clearly after he emerged from the toilet, he was repaired. We see him fixed later on.